# Stuck attempting to federate domain for office 365 with Google SAML

Tags: powershell, office365, single-sign-on

Attempting to set up Office365 to have SAML SSO through Google with user Auto Provisioning.

Following the Google support documentation at [Set up SSO via SAML for Microsoft Office 365](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F6363817%3Fhl%3Den&assistant_id=generic-unu&product_context=6363817&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a)

Our domains are showing as managed when running Get-MsolDomain:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-MsolDomain

Name                       Status   Authentication
----                       ------   --------------
ourDomain.com             Verified Managed
ourDomain.onmicrosoft.com Verified Managed
```

Connect-MsolDomain prompts for login; logged in as GA account for our Office365 tenant and running in an administrator window on Windows 10. When we get to the step to call Set-MsolDomainAuthentication we receive:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-MsolDomainAuthentication -DomainName $DomainName -Authentication federated
Set-MsolDomainAuthentication : You cannot remove this domain as the default domain without replacing it with another default domain. Use the the Set-MsolDomain cmdlet to set another domain as the default domain before you delete this domain.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-MsolDomainAuthentication -DomainName $DomainName -Authentication  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolDomainAuthentication], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.DefaultDomainUnsetException,Microsoft.Online.
   Administration.Automation.SetDomainAuthentication
```

After transitioning the ourDomain.onmicrosoft.com to primary and re-running the command, we're met with:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-MsolDomainAuthentication -DomainName $DomainName -Authentication Federated
Set-MsolDomainAuthentication : Unable to complete this action. Try again later.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-MsolDomainAuthentication -DomainName $DomainName -Authenticati ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolDomainAuthentication], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.InternalServiceException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetDomainAuthentication
```

We waited over 12 hours and re-ran with the same results. Has anyone else experienced this and can provide guidance?

Additional Info, we have opened a ticket with Microsoft and are attempting to gain access to an old account manager account. When running confirm-MsolDomain for our domain we receive this return:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Confirm-MsolDomain -DomainName ourDomain.com
Confirm-MsolDomain : Unable to verify this domain because it is used elsewhere in Office 365. Remove the verified domain from the other service before adding it here.
At line:1 char:1
+ Confirm-MsolDomain -DomainName ourDomain.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Confirm-MsolDomain], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.DomainAlreadyExistsException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConfirmDomain
```

Comment: Ever used godaddy or proofpoint with that domain? Those would the first two I checked with.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We had missed a step of our configuration with  Set-MsolDomainAuthentication. Reviewing our command logs we were able to adjust parameters and re-run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

After adjusting our variable parameters, we were able to successfully run the command and set domain to federated.

```
$dom = "ourDomain.com"
$BrandName = "Whatever you want it to be"
$LogOnUrl = GoogleSSOURL
$LogOffUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/logout"
$ecpUrl = GoogleSSOURL
$MyURI = GoogleEntityID
$MySigningCert = CertFromGoogle
$uri = GoogleEntityID
$Protocol = "SAMLP"

Set-MsolDomainAuthentication
   -DomainName $dom
   -FederationBrandName $BrandName
   -Authentication Federated
   -PassiveLogOnUri $LogOnUrl
   -ActiveLogOnUri $ecpUrl
   -SigningCertificate $MySigningCert
   -IssuerUri $MyURI
   -LogOffUri $LogOffUrl
  -PreferredAuthenticationProtocol $Protocol
```

We followed the the guidance from a combination of [Google](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F6363817%3Fhl%3Den&assistant_id=generic-unu&product_context=6363817&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a) and [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/connect/how-to-connect-fed-saml-idp) documentation.